1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in /typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/CropViewHelper.php
I have a strange problem with TYPO3 12.4.20I've updated this instance from 11.x and now I can't open - Settings - Configure Installation-Wide OptionsAfter click on "Configure options" button I have an exception:"Something went wrongPlease use Check for broken extensions to see if a loaded extension breaks this part of the install tool and unload it.
The box below may additionally reveal further details on what went wrong depending on your debug settings. It may help to temporarily switch to debug mode using Settings > Configuration Presets > Debug settings.
If this error happens at an early state and no full exception back trace is shown, it may also help to manually increase debugging output in %config-dir%/system/settings.php:['BE']['debug'] => true, ['SYS']['devIPmask'] => '*', ['SYS']['displayErrors'] => 1,['SYS']['exceptionalErrors'] => 12290"And this code in AJAX error (I've tried to uninstall all custom extensions but with no success)
Thu, 10 Oct 2024 06:51:02 +0000 [CRITICAL] request="48439121326cb" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.DebugExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB: BE): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception, code #1476107295, file /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 138: PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/CropViewHelper.php line 117- Exception: PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/CropViewHelper.php line 117, in file /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php:138 - {"mode":"WEB","application_mode":"BE","exception_class":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\Exception","exception_code":1476107295,"file":"/var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php","line":138,"message":"PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/CropViewHelper.php line 117","request_url":"https://site/typo3/install.php?install%5Bcontroller%5D=settings&install%5Bcontext%5D=backend&install%5Baction%5D=localConfigurationGetContent","exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\Exception: PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/CropViewHelper.php line 117 in /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php:138\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/CropViewHelper.php(117): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Error\\ErrorHandler->handleError()\n#1 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/Traits/CompileWithRenderStatic.php(31): TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\Format\\CropViewHelper::renderStatic()\n#2 [internal function]: TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\Format\\CropViewHelper->render()\n#3 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(272): call_user_func()\n#4 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(260): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->callRenderMethod()\n#5 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/ViewHelperInvoker.php(79): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->initializeArgumentsAndRender()\n#6 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/ViewHelperNode.php(135): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\ViewHelperInvoker->invoke()\n#7 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/AbstractNode.php(57): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\ViewHelperNode->evaluate()\n#8 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/AbstractNode.php(37): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\AbstractNode->evaluateChildNode()\n#9 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(329): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\AbstractNode->evaluateChildNodes()\n#10 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(307): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\{closure}()\n#11 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractConditionViewHelper.php(175): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->renderChildren()\n#12 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractConditionViewHelper.php(61): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractConditionViewHelper->renderThenChild()\n#13 [internal function]: TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractConditionViewHelper->render()\n#14 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(272): call_user_func()\n#15 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(260): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->callRenderMethod()\n#16 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/ViewHelperInvoker.php(79): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->initializeArgumentsAndRender()\n#17 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/ViewHelperNode.php(135): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\ViewHelperInvoker->invoke()\n#18 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/AbstractNode.php(57): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\ViewHelperNode->evaluate()\n#19 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/AbstractNode.php(37): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\AbstractNode->evaluateChildNode()\n#20 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(329): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\AbstractNode->evaluateChildNodes()\n#21 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(307): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\{closure}()\n#22 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/ViewHelpers/ElseViewHelper.php(58): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->renderChildren()\n#23 [internal function]: TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\ElseViewHelper->render()\n#24 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(272): call_user_func()\n#25 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(260): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->callRenderMethod()\n#26 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/ViewHelperInvoker.php(79): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->initializeArgumentsAndRender()\n#27 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/ViewHelperNode.php(135): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\ViewHelperInvoker->invoke()\n#28 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractConditionViewHelper.php(208): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\ViewHelperNode->evaluate()\n#29 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractConditionViewHelper.php(63): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractConditionViewHelper->renderElseChild()\n#30 [internal function]: TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractConditionViewHelper->render()\n#31 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(272): call_user_func()\n#32 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(260): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->callRenderMethod()\n#33 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/ViewHelperInvoker.php(79): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->initializeArgumentsAndRender()\n#34 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/ViewHelperNode.php(135): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\ViewHelperInvoker->invoke()\n#35 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/AbstractNode.php(57): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\ViewHelperNode->evaluate()\n#36 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/AbstractNode.php(37): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\AbstractNode->evaluateChildNode()\n#37 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper.php(329): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\Parser\\SyntaxTree\\AbstractNode->evaluateChildNodes()\n#38 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/ViewHelpers/ForViewHelper.php(149): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\{closure}()\n#39 /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/Traits/CompileWithRenderStatic.php(31): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\
Any ideas?

Did you already address all breaking changes during your update and modified code accordingly?
The error messages sounds as if your LocalConfiguration may have entries in there that are tried to be handled as a string while they come in as an array
Can you try to remove all customozation from your local configuration file(s) and see if that helps? If so, you can add your config back in piece by piece to find the culprit.

Thanks for your opinion!
Yes, I've checked my LocalConfiguration.php and tried to competelly delete all custom extensions and 3rd party, line news, powermail, etc.
In finally I leave only typo3/cms-*  but still have an error.
Syntax of this file looks like good and without any problem.

you use composer mode, right? So you uninstalled all the mentioned extensions, or how did you try it? Note that v12 in composer mode would use a file in config/system/settings.php and no longer LocalConfiguration.php. Maybe that migration somehow failed?!

Thanks for your comment Garvin.
You're right - I've changed config.php instead of LocalConfiguration.php
Finally I found a problem in config.php
in 'MAIL' => [ section
this part broke "Configure options" functionality:
"transport_smtp_stream_options" => [
            "ssl" => [
                "verify_peer" => false,
                "verify_peer_name" => false,
            ],
        ],


Same problem here.
The code that breaks the "Configure options" functionality is
'MAIL' => [
    ...
    'transport_smtp_stream_options' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
],

But this only happens if the code is in the file settings.php. If you write it in the file additional.php, it should work.
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['transport_smtp_stream_options']['ssl']['verify_peer'] = false;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL']['transport_smtp_stream_options']['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = false;

The problem has existed since TYPO3 Version 12.4.18.
